# How to publish an Angular Shared library to private a git server

Tags: angular, git, npm, git-subtree, angular-library

I've made an angular 6 library using `ng generate library my-lib`, and now I need to publish it, however it cannot go to NPM since its a private code.

At my company we have a private git server and I need to publish there, we already have some NPM Node.js libraries published there but publishing the Angular one giving us trouble.

I've managed to build the library with `ng build my-lib` then `cd dist/my-lib` and packing it with `npm pack` that gives me a the `.tgz` bundled library that can be installed directly to another project.

However this is not a good solution for distributing controlled versions.

So after some research I've found the best candidate so far, that is using `git subtree`, in order to place the `dist/my-lib` into another repo, then it can be installed to another project easily with `npm install git+ssh://git@server:/git/my-lib-dist.git`
Based on this guide [Share Angular 6 Library between Multiple Apps](https://medium.com/@sunnysun_5694/share-angular-6-library-between-multiple-apps-275c11757ffc)

So I created a secondary repo, and then with:
`git subtree add --prefix dist/my-lib MY-REMOTE master`

And push the changes with:
`git subtree push --prefix dist/my-lib MY-REMOTE master`

This works fine, but there is a problem, I had to remove the `/dist` folder from my `.gitignore` in order for it to work, and now git tracks the changes of the built library, and I have to commit and push it to the repo, and the built libraries are quite heavy.

How can I have the `dist/my-lib` folder pushed to the dist repository, and not have it tracked or pushed to the source repository?

Is this the best approach to my question or is there a better alternative.

Comment: What about publishing to a private [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-oss) ? It will be compatible with `npm install` etc.

Comment: Have you tried to make your `dist/lib` as `git submodule`?

Comment: How exactly? I think I went through this option but I think it wasnt suitable because the dist/ folder was being tracked by the main repo making development a real pain. Or Maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: @JoãoEduardoSoareseSilva FYI, the person who left that comment doesn't have enough reputation to use the comment privilege (they posted an answer that was converted to a comment - that's how it exists, but they can't reply to you again).